# inertiajs with boostrap and laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, inertiajs

First question here ;)

I'm learning inertia JS with laravel 8 with Vue JS (2.6) and created a basic auth system.
Now problem I'm facing that There is a sample bootstrap page which works well when load the page (Refresh). But when I call post login route and redirect it back to home the UI got destroyed and once I refresh the page UI works well as it should be ?

So is there any workaround it or inertiajs is not compatible with twitter bootstrap ?

Edit : Also tried with Tailwind CSS 2.x but got same result why UI is getting destroyed.

[UI With Refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z29up.png)

[UI After Login redirect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNfJK.png)

Comment: Since you're using Inertia, can you clarify which front-end stack you're using, besides Bootstrap as a css/js framework? Inertia relies on a front-end stack such as Vue, React or Svelte to work properly.

Comment: I'm using vue js for front end with vue version 2.6+
and for UI kit I'm using Bootstrap v5.

Comment: There are a lot of variables which we don't know here. You could take a look at [Ping CRM](https://github.com/inertiajs/pingcrm), an example project in Laravel + Vue, to determine what differs from your project.

Comment: Please, add your source code here to make it more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attention !!

I tried in a fresh laravel and everything got works

There is no issue now.

May be some css compilation got wrong.

I tried without / with laravel ui 3.0 and work fine now.

Thanks mate who replied ☺️